# How to map a bunch of objects in js to another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object and I need to return each one to check for its mapping result. 
My problem with my code below is on this line

```
style: { ...map[settings] },
```

I need a way to go through each setting and pass it to map. Not sure how to go about that the most efficient way in es6 ?

**This is the value of settings been passed into the PassThrough component**

```
const settings = {
  block_background: GradientGreen,
  block_spacing: padding,
};
```

**Here is my Component**

```
const PassThrough = ({ children, settings }) => {
  const map = {
    GradientGreen: {
      background: 'linear-gradient(-95deg, green, blue 100%)',
    },
    padding: '20px',
  };

  const cloneChild = () => {
    return cloneElement(children, {
      style: { ...map[settings] },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {cloneChild()}
    <Fragment/>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest is probably:

```
 inlineStyle: Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(settings).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: map[v] })))
```

But actually I would change `settings` to:

```
const settings = original => {
 block_background: original.GradientGreen,
 block_spacing: original.padding,
};
```

Then it is just:

```
inlineStlye: settings(map)
```

Comment: I can't change settings its coming from a server. This seems to be returning the incorrect values. Seems to be returning the settings object and not the map values

Comment: @me-me what output do you expect?

Comment: You're code is right it was mine that was off. Thank you for this its exactly what I'm after

Comment: I changed your code a little to work with what I'm after. But the issue is the values are coming back as an object with keys associated to them. I'm looking to combine both into one. I feel like I'm better off starting another thread based on the new code.

Comment: @me-me whoops, fixed that

Comment: Perfect so Object.assign({}, ... ) was the glue. Thank you.